# Ajuda com a api do google maps

Tags: google-maps

Sou iniciante em HTML e PHP, gostaria de saber como posso via API do google maps fazer no meu site uma rotina parecida com a do Site [mapeia.com.br](http://www.mapeia.com.br/), onde eu receba as informações de quilometragem e tempo de uma rota informada pelo usuário.

Comment: Da uma olhada em Serviço Distance Matrix https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta simples: Muito PHP (ou a linguagem server de sua preferência), bastante javascript, muita leitura da documentação e um pouco de HTML**

Resposta não tão simples: Isso vai requerer um pouco da sua criatividade. A API do google te dá um suporte para você usar em suas aplicações, ela não te dá a solução pronta. Recomendo fazer vários testes da [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=pt-br) (estudar mesmo, como se fosse capítulo por capítulo), testar vários modelos de mapas, fazer alterações. Lá tem os códigos. Uma outra maneira para se inspirar é saber o que outros desenvolvedores estão fazendo com o Google Maps API. Neste [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples) tem um excelente repositório no github com vários exemplos prontos para você testar em sua pesquisa. O que você talvez vá torcer o nariz, é que iniciantes (como você diz que é) talvez não tenha tanta intimidade com banco de dados. Se for o caso, recomendo estudar padrão JSON de leitura de arquivo, estudar a função [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) do PHP, e estudar também a função [fwrite](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php) de escrita de arquivo. Mais tarde você pode fazer essa leitura JSON partir de um banco de dados (é possível). Antes de começar pela parte mais engenhosa, você pode simplesmente passar parâmetros GET na url para testar um dinamismo.

Exemplo do uso da função json_decode:

```
<?php
$arquivo = "teste.json"; // Sempre colocar caminho completo para possível saída HTTP. Configurar token.php para evitar acessos indevidos. 
$info    = file_get_contents($arquivo);
$lendo   = json_decode($info);
foreach ($lendo->dados as $reg) {
                echo "<b>id:</b> " . $reg->id."<br>";
                echo "<br /><b>categoria:</b> " . $reg->Categoria."<br>";
                echo "<br /><b>titulo:</b> " . $reg->titulo ."<br>";
}

?>
```

Arquivo JSON usado

```
{
    "dados":[ {
        "id": "1", "Categoria": "Blog", "titulo": "Minha postagem"
    }
    ,
    {
        "Id": "0", "Categoria": "00000", "Titulo": "000000"
    }
    ]
}
```

Exemplo de um mapa recebendo dados via URL do PHP

```
<?php
$pegaLatitude = $_GET['lat]';
$pegaLongitude = $_GET['lng]';

?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map;
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: <?php echo $pegaLatidude; ?>, lng: <?php echo $pegaLongitude; ?>},
              zoom: 8
            });
          }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

> Conclusão: A API do Google Maps oferece apenas o serviço de
>   manipulação de mapas. O papel do desenvolvedor é entregar soluções de
>   mercado. Estude, mas não seja um "wiker", seja um desenvolvedor. Crie
>   sistemas, soluções. E principalmente, tente não associar tão
>   diretamente sua capacidade de resolver problemas a **apenas** limites
>   de conhecimento. Em grande parte da rotina de desenvolvedor é usar
>   recursos de conhecimento de outros desenvolvedores, usando APIs,
>   bibliotecas e frameworks. Por isso, não tenha receio em
>   pesquisar/perguntar/etc. E não esqueça de pegar a sua chave de desenvolvedor para seus mapas funcionarem. Mais explicações neste [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key?hl=pt-br)